# ARM assembler return pointer

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am currently working on a project where I need to return a pointer to a double from an ARM assembly function to a C program.

I currently tackle this problem by pushing the double onto the stack and then returning the address of the stack pointer.

However I am not sure if that's the best (safest) way to go about it, hence why I'm asking here for either confirmation that this is a good way to do it or an alternative solution.

The additional problem is that according to the task i'm not allowed to hand another variable in neither am I allowed to use the C malloc function.

Edit: I solved the problem by creating a variable in .data and then just simply return the address of that field.

Comment: You should not return a pointer to a local, that's not legal in C either.

Comment: Okay so if I return the stack pointer that would be returning a pointer to a local variable. What other option is there to put a double in memory and return that pointer without having to use the C malloc?

Comment: If you don't particularly care about reentrancy, declare a variable in your data section. You should really pass in the pointer to your function though.

Comment: Well I would if I could, the problem is that the function declared in the task specifically asks for a pointer as the return value and no pointer as input.

Comment: Why can't you return a `double` by value?  Or have the caller pass a pointer for you to store into?  Normally you only need to return a pointer if it's a newly-allocated object (with `malloc`, like `strdup` does).  Returning a pointer to a static buffer is used in some legacy C library functions, like `gethostbyname`, but that's only useful with struct return types that would be inefficient to return by value.  `double` is not like that: it fits in a register (unless you're using soft-float, in which case it fits in two integer registers).

Comment: It is indeed soft-float. I don't know why they formulated the task the way they did, I don't find it particularly elegant either. I'll contact my supervisor and ask if it's okay to change the return value to by value instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should think how you will do in pure C! You cannot allocate a `double` on the stack. You either reserve the memory before calling your assembly function. Example

```
void my_assembly(double* value) {
    *value = (...);
}

void main(void) {
    double value;

    my_assembly(&value);
}
```

Or you allocate it into your assembly function:

```
double* my_assembly(void) {
    double *value = malloc(sizeof(double));
    *value = (...);
    return value;
}

void main() {
    double* value = my_assembly();
}
```

Another option would be to return the double! [ARM's Procedure call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) says at `5.4 Result Return`:

> A double-word sized Fundamental Data Type (e.g., long long, double and 64-bit containerized vectors) is returned in r0 and r1